# Merging multiple Google calendar feeds into one JSON object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-calendar-api

I am trying to bring in the JSON feeds from multiple Google calendars so that I can sort the upcoming events and display the next X number in an "Upcoming Events" list.

I have this working with Yahoo! pipes but I want to get away from using a 3rd party to aggregate. I think I am close, but I cannot get the JSON objects created correctly. I am getting the data into the array but not in JSON format, so I can't manipulate it.

I have tried `var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(JSONData);` using https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js but that just threw errors. I suspect because my variable is in the wrong starting format. I have tried just calling the feed like: `$.getJSON(url);` and creating a `function concant1()` to do the `JSONData=JSONData.concat(data);`, but it doesn't fire and I think it would produce the same end result anyway. I have also tried several other methods of getting the end result I want with varying degrees of doom. Here is the closest I have come so far:

```
var JSONData = new Array();
var urllist = ["https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/dg61asqgqg4pust2l20obgdl64%40group.calendar.google.com/public/full?orderby=starttime&max-results=3&sortorder=ascending&futureevents=true&ctz=America/New_York&singleevents=true&alt=json&callback=concant1","https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/5oc3kvp7lnu5rd4krg2skcu2ng%40group.calendar.google.com/public/full?orderby=starttime&max-results=3&sortorder=ascending&futureevents=true&ctz=America/New_York&singleevents=true&alt=json&callback=concant1","http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/rine4umu96kl6t46v4fartnho8%40group.calendar.google.com/public/full?orderby=starttime&max-results=3&sortorder=ascending&futureevents=true&ctz=America/New_York&singleevents=true&alt=json&callback=concant1"];

urllist.forEach(function addFeed(url){
    alert("The URL being used: "+ url);
    if (void 0 != JSONData){JSONData=JSONData.concat($.getJSON(url));}
    else{JSONData = $.getJSON(url);}
    alert("The count from concantonated JSONData: "+JSONData.length); 
});

document.write("The final count from JSONData: "+JSONData.length+"<p>");
console.log(JSONData)
```

**UPDATE:** 
Now with full working source!! :) If anyone would like to make suggestions on how to improve the code's efficiency it would be gratefully accepted. I hope others find this useful.:

```
// GCal MFA - Google Calendar Multiple Feed Aggregator
// Useage: GCalMFA(CIDs,n); 
// Where 'CIDs' is a list of comma seperated Google calendar IDs in the format: id@group.calendar.google.com, and 'n' is the number of results to display.
// While the contained console.log(); outputs are really handy for testing, you will probably want to remove them for regular usage
// Author: Jeramy Kruser - http://jeramy.kruser.me

// This is error-checking code for IE and can be removed
// onerror=function (d, f, g){alert (d+ "\n"+ f+ "\n");}
// This keeps IE from complaining about console.log and can be removed if all the console.log testing statements are removed
// if (!window.console) {console = {log: function() {}};}

// Add a tag to your page to identify it as js-enabled for CSS purposes
document.body.className += ' js-enabled';

// Global variables
var urllist = [];
var maxResults = 3; // The default is 3 results unless a value is sent
var JSONData = {};
var eventCount = 0;
var errorLog = "";

JSONData = { count: 0,
    value : {
    description: "Aggregates multiple Google calendar feeds into a single sorted list",
    generator: "StackOverflow communal coding - Thanks for the assist Patrick M",
    website: "http://jeramy.kruser.me",
    author: "Jeramy & Kasey Kruser",
    items: []
}};

// Prototype forEach required for IE
if ( !Array.prototype.forEach ) {
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
    for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
      fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
    }
  }
}

// For putting dates from feed into a format that can be read by the Date function for calculating event length.
function parse (str) {
        // validate year as 4 digits, month as 01-12, and day as 01-31 
        str = str.match (/^(\d{4})(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])$/);
        if (str) {
           // make a date
           str[0] = new Date ( + str[1], + str[2] - 1, + str[3]);
           // check if month stayed the same (ie that day number is valid)
           if (str[0].getMonth () === + str[2] - 1) {
              return str[0];
              }
        }
        return undefined;
 }

//For outputting to HTML
function output() {
    var months, day_in_ms, summary, i, item, eventlink, title, calendar, where,dtstart, dtend, endyear, endmonth, endday, startyear, startmonth, startday, endmonthdayyear, eventlinktitle, startmonthday, length, curtextval, k;
    // Array of month names from numbers for page display.
    months = {'0':'January', '1':'February', '2':'March', '3':'April', '4':'May', '5':'June', '6':'July', '7':'August', '8':'September', '9':'October', '10':'November', '11':'December'};
    // For use in calculating event length.
    day_in_ms = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    // Instantiate HTML Arrays.
    summary = [];
    for (i = 0; i < maxResults; i+=1 ) {
        // console.log("i: "+i+" < "+"maxResults: "+ maxResults);
        if (!(JSONData.value.items[i] === undefined)) {     
            item = JSONData.value.items[i];
            // Grabbing data for each event in the feed.
            eventlink = (item.link[0].href);
            title = item.title.$t; 
            // Only display the calendar title if there is more than one 
            calendar = "";
            if (urllist.length > 1) {
                calendar = '<br />Calendar: <a href="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=' + item.gd$who[0].email + '&ctz=America/New_York">' + item.gd$who[0].valueString + '<\/a> (<a href="https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/' + item.gd$who[0].email + '/public/basic.ics">iCal<\/a>)'; 
            }
            // Grabbing event location, if entered.
            if ( item.gd$where[0].valueString !== "" ) {
                where = '<br />' + (item.gd$where[0].valueString); 
                }
            else {
                where = (""); 
                }
            // Grabbing start date and putting in form YYYYmmdd. Subtracting one day from dtend without a specified end time (which contains colons) to fix Google's habit of ending an all-day event at midnight on the following day.
            dtstart = new Date(parse(((item.gd$when[0].startTime).substring(0,10)).replace(/-/g,"")));
            if((item.gd$when[0].endTime).indexOf(':') === -1) {
                  dtend = new Date(parse(((item.gd$when[0].endTime).substring(0,10)).replace(/-/g,"")) - day_in_ms);
                }
            else {
                  dtend = new Date(parse(((item.gd$when[0].endTime).substring(0,10)).replace(/-/g,"")));
                }
            // Put dates in pretty form for display.
            endyear = dtend.getFullYear();  
            endmonth = months[dtend.getMonth()];
            endday = dtend.getDate();
            startyear = dtstart.getFullYear();  
            startmonth = months[dtstart.getMonth()];
            startday = dtstart.getDate();
            //consolidate some much-used variables for HTML output.
            endmonthdayyear = endmonth + ' ' + endday + ', ' + endyear;
            eventlinktitle = '<a href="' + eventlink + '">' + title + '<\/a>';
            startmonthday = startmonth + ' ' + startday;
            // Calculates the number of days between each event's start and end dates. 
            length = ((dtend - dtstart) / day_in_ms);
            // HTML for each event, depending on which div is available on the page (different HTML applies). Only one div can exist on any one page. 
            if (document.getElementById("homeCalendar") !== null ) {
                // If the length of the event is greater than 0 days, show start and end dates. 
                if ( length > 0 && startmonth !== endmonth && startday === endday ) {       
                        summary[i] = ('<h3>' + eventlink + '">' + startmonthday + ', ' + startyear + ' - ' + endmonthdayyear + '<\/a><\/h3><p>' + title + '<\/p>'); }
                    // If the length of the event is greater than 0 and begins and ends within the same month, shorten the date display.
                    else if ( length > 0 && startmonth === endmonth && startyear === endyear ) {        
                        summary[i] = ('<h3><a href="' + eventlink + '">' + startmonthday + '-' + endday + ', ' + endyear + '<\/a><\/h3><p>' + title + '<\/p>'); }
                    // If the length of the event is greater than 0 and begins and ends within different months of the same year, shorten the date display.
                    else if ( length > 0 && startmonth !== endmonth && startyear === endyear ) {        
                        summary[i] = ('<h3><a href="' + eventlink + '">' + startmonthday + ' - ' + endmonthdayyear + '<\/a><\/h3><p>' + title + '<\/p>'); }
                    // If the length of the event is less than one day (length < = 0), show only the start date.
                    else { 
                        summary[i] = ('<h3><a href="' + eventlink + '">' + startmonthday + ', ' + startyear + '<\/a><\/h3><p>' + title + '<\/p>'); }
            }        
            else if (document.getElementById("allCalendar") !== null ) {
                // If the length of the event is greater than 0 days, show start and end dates. 
                 if ( length > 0 && startmonth !== endmonth && startday === endday ) {           
                           summary[i] = ('<li>' + eventlinktitle + '<br />' + startmonthday + ', ' + startyear + ' - ' + endmonthdayyear + where + calendar + '<\/li>'); } 
                      // If the length of the event is greater than 0 and begins and ends within the same month, shorten the date display. 
                      else if ( length > 0 && startmonth === endmonth && startyear === endyear ) {           
                           summary[i] = ('<li>' + eventlinktitle + '<br />' + startmonthday + '-' + endday + ', ' + endyear + where + calendar + '<\/li>'); } 
                      // If the length of the event is greater than 0 and begins and ends within different months of the same year, shorten the date display. 
                      else if ( length > 0 && startmonth !== endmonth && startyear === endyear ) {           
                           summary[i] = ('<li>' + eventlinktitle + '<br />' + startmonthday + ' - ' + endmonthdayyear + where + calendar + '<\/li>'); } 
                      // If the length of the event is less than one day (length < = 0), show only the start date. 
                      else {  
                           summary[i] = ('<li>' + eventlinktitle + '<br />' + startmonthday + ', ' + startyear + where + calendar + '<\/li>'); }
            } 
        }
        if (summary[i] === undefined) { summary[i] = "";}
        // console.log(summary[i]);
    }
    // console.log(JSONData);
    // Puts the HTML into the div with the appropriate id. Each page can have only one.
    if (document.getElementById("homeCalendar") !== null ) {
        curtextval = document.getElementById("homeCalendar");
        // console.log("homeCalendar: "+curtextval);
        }
    else if (document.getElementById("oneCalendar") !== null ) {
        curtextval = document.getElementById("oneCalendar");
        // console.log("oneCalendar: "+curtextval);
         }
    else if (document.getElementById("allCalendar") !== null ) {
        curtextval = document.getElementById("allCalendar");
        // console.log("allCalendar: "+curtextval.innerHTML);
         }
    for (k = 0; k<maxResults; k+=1 ) { curtextval.innerHTML = curtextval.innerHTML + summary[k]; }
    if (JSONData.count === 0) {
        errorLog += '<div id="noEvents">No events found.</div>';
    }
    if (document.getElementById("homeCalendar") === null ) {
        curtextval.innerHTML = '<ul>' + curtextval.innerHTML + '<\/ul>'; 
        }
    if (errorLog !== "") {
        curtextval.innerHTML += errorLog;
        }
}

// For taking in each feed, breaking out the events and sorting them into the object by date
function sortFeed(event) {  
    var tempEntry, i;
    tempEntry = event;
    i = 0;
    // console.log("*** New incoming event object #"+eventCount+" ***");
    // console.log(event.title.$t);
    // console.log(event);
    // console.log("i = " + i + " and maxResults " + maxResults);
    while(i<maxResults) {
        // console.log("i = " + i + " < maxResults " + maxResults);
        // console.log("Sorting event = " + event.title.$t + " by date of " + event.gd$when[0].startTime.substring(0,10).replace(/-/g,""));
        if (JSONData.value.items[i]) {
            // console.log("JSONData.value.items[" + i + "] exists and has a startTime of " + JSONData.value.items[i].gd$when[0].startTime.substring(0,10).replace(/-/g,""));
            if (event.gd$when[0].startTime.substring(0,10).replace(/-/g,"")<JSONData.value.items[i].gd$when[0].startTime.substring(0,10).replace(/-/g,"")) {
                // console.log("The incoming event value of " + event.gd$when[0].startTime.substring(0,10).replace(/-/g,"") + " is < " + JSONData.value.items[i].gd$when[0].startTime.substring(0,10).replace(/-/g,""));
                tempEntry = JSONData.value.items[i];
                // console.log("Existing JSONData.value.items[" + i + "] value " + JSONData.value.items[i].gd$when[0].startTime.substring(0,10).replace(/-/g,"") + " stored in tempEntry");
                JSONData.value.items[i] = event;
                // console.log("Position JSONData.value.items[" + i + "] set to new value: " + event.gd$when[0].startTime.substring(0,10).replace(/-/g,""));
                event = tempEntry;
                // console.log("Now sorting event = " + event.title.$t + " by date of " + event.gd$when[0].startTime.substring(0,10).replace(/-/g,""));
            }
            else {
                // console.log("The incoming event value of " + event.gd$when[0].startTime.substring(0,10).replace(/-/g,"") + " is > " + JSONData.value.items[i].gd$when[0].startTime.substring(0,10).replace(/-/g,"") + " moving on...");
            }
        }
        else {
            JSONData.value.items[i] = event;
            // console.log("JSONData.value.items[" + i + "] does not exist so it was set to the Incoming value of " + event.gd$when[0].startTime.substring(0,10).replace(/-/g,""));
            i = maxResults;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
}

// For completing the aggregation
function complete(result) {
    // Track the number of calls completed back, we're not done until all URLs have processed
    if( complete.count === undefined ){
        complete.count = urllist.length;        
    }
    // console.log("complete.count = "+complete.count);
    // console.log(result.feed);
    if(result.feed.entry){
        JSONData.count = maxResults;
        // Check each incoming item against JSONData.value.items
        // console.log("*** Begin Sorting " + result.feed.entry.length + " Events ***");
        // console.log(result.feed.entry);
        result.feed.entry.forEach(
            function(event){
                eventCount += 1;
                sortFeed(event);                
            }
        );
    }
    if( (complete.count-=1)<1 ) {
        // console.log("*** Done Sorting ***");
        output();
    }
}

// This is the main function. It takes in the list of Calendar IDs and the number of results to display
function GCalMFA(list,results){
        var i, calPreProperties, calPostProperties1, calPostProperties2;
        calPreProperties = "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/";
        calPostProperties1 = "/public/full?max-results=";
        calPostProperties2 = "&orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending&futureevents=true&ctz=America/New_York&singleevents=true&alt=json&callback=?";

        if (list) {
            if (results) {
                maxResults = results;
            }
            urllist = list.split(',');
            for (i = 0; i < urllist.length; i+=1 ){
                // console.log(urllist[i]);
                if (urllist[i] === ""){ urllist.splice(i,1);}
                else{
                urllist[i] = calPreProperties + urllist[i] + calPostProperties1+maxResults+calPostProperties2;}
            }
            // console.log("There are " + urllist.length + " URLs");
            urllist.forEach(function addFeed(url){
                $.getJSON(url, complete);   
            });
        }
        else {
            errorLog += '<div id="noURLs">No calendars have been selected.</div>';
            output();
        }
}
```

Comment: You're specifying the callback function in your url list: `&callback=concant1`. Is that intentional? I thought you had to specify the callback in the params to `$.getJSON` and leave the url as `&callback=?` for it to work properly. Also, `$.getJSON` doesn't return anything itself, so pasing it to JSONData.concat won't do anything (I don't think).

Comment: The variable gets filled regardless of whether `&callback=concant1` is set. And `$.getJSON` does return a value. It is shown in the structure of `JSONData` shown above.

Comment: Well, I learned something new today. It does indeed return the XmlHttpRequest object, which obviously discovered is not the data that you need. I'll try putting together a fiddle and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with pretty much your original code: http://jsfiddle.net/ynuQ5/ I'm working on making it do what you want.

Comment: That is awesome. Thank you for taking the time to look at it. I am continuing to bang on it myself. The links I provided above are static for sake of people looking at the code. My working page is at: http://kruser.me/json-full.html If I get any more of it working I will update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, here's the gist of what needs to change.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ynuQ5/2/

Don't `concat` on the return value of `$.getJSON`. As I mentioned above, that gets you the XMLHttpRequest object, which is a lot more than the data you're interested in. Critically, however, at that point the request hasn't been made and the data isn't available yet.

Instead, handle it in callback for the AJAX request. I updated your URL list to use `&callback=?`, initialize the JSONData var to look more like the structure in your 2nd screenshot and then changed the javascript for the AJAX requests to this:

```
var JSONData = { count: 0,
    value : {
        description: "Calendars from the Unitarian Universalist Association (UUA.org)",
        generator: "StackOverflow communal coding",
        items: []
}};

// url list declaration goes here    

urllist.forEach(function addFeed(url){
    $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
        if(!result.feed.entry) {
            console.log("No entries from " + url);
            return;
        }
        JSONData.count += result.feed.entry.length;
        JSONData.value.items = JSONData.value.items.concat(result.feed.entry);
        console.log(JSONData);
    });
});
```

Right away you'll notice there are still some discrepancies between the raw data you get back from google and the data provided by the Yahoo pipe transform. Noticeably, a lot of their provided values have been transformed from objects to texts. For example, google gives us this:

```
id: Object
    $t: "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/5oc3kvp7lnu5rd4krg2skcu2ng%40group.calendar.google.com/public/full/bbidp5qb4vh5vk9apok1cpnino_20130119"
link: Array[2]
    0: Object
        href: "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=YmJpZHA1cWI0dmg1dms5YXBvazFjcG5pbm9fMjAxMzAxMTkgNW9jM2t2cDdsbnU1cmQ0a3JnMnNrY3UybmdAZw"
        rel: "alternate"
        title: "alternate"
        type: "text/html"
    1: Object
    length: 2
published: Object
    $t: "2012-11-13T15:59:31.000-05:00"
title: Object
    $t: "30 Days of Love"
    type: "text"
updated: Object
    $t: "2012-11-13T15:59:31.000-05:00"
```

Where as your yahoo transform returns data more like this:

```
id: "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/5oc3kvp7lnu5rd4krg2skcu2ng%40group.calendar.google.com/public/full/bbidp5qb4vh5vk9apok1cpnino_20130119"
link: "href: "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=YmJpZHA1cWI0dmg1dms5YXBvazFjcG5pbm9fMjAxMzAxMTkgNW9jM2t2cDdsbnU1cmQ0a3JnMnNrY3UybmdAZw"
published: "2012-11-13T15:59:31.000-05:00"
title: "30 Days of Love"
updated: "2012-11-13T15:59:31.000-05:00"
```

You can transform the data more when you receive it. Or you can modify your display code to use the more convoluted, raw values.

Let me know if I can clear anything up in my code or response.

Edit: Updated fiddle showing how to access author (aka feed name, apparently), start time and title: http://jsfiddle.net/ynuQ5/8/
Let me know if there's more specific stuff you want out of it :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. Sigh...I was really close with an earlier attempt which I had given up on when I didn't get it to work properly. I had tried to `JSONData=JSONData.concat(feeddata);` instead of the proper `JSONData.value.items = JSONData.value.items.concat(result.feed.entry);` Thank you so much. I have to edit my display code a bit, but that is really minor now that I have the structure so I can get at the data I need.

Comment: WEll. I figured it would be easy enough, but I am having trouble accessing the data. I tried listing the properties using
`var keys = Object.keys(JSONData.value.items);`
I get good response until I get to JSONData.value.items, then nothing. I thought maybe JSONData.value.items[i] but that throws an error. If you have time could you help me out one more time with either how to access the data now that I have it, or as you said above, how to "transform the data more." I assume that modifying the display code will be simpler once I figure out how to address the data I want. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, I could give a few more tips. What are the main things you want to address? I'm assuming title, date, and link are important. If you update your question or ask a new question with a list, I will answer back.

Comment: From each item I need to address:
`title $t,
author 0 name $t,
link 0,
content $t,
gd$when 0 startTime,
gd$when 0 endTime,
gdwhere 0`

But, even if you can show me how to access one or two of the item sub-elements I am sure I can figure the rest out. I have used the format `obj.key.key[i]` before but it doesn't seem to work with this object. I am sure I am just missing something simple. I did some Googling but I think I may be asking the wrong questions.

Comment: Okay, so I am confused. In your http://jsfiddle.net/ynuQ5/8/ (which is awesome, thank you by the way!), you use: `var item = JSONData.value.items[i]; str += item.author[0].name.$t...` If you can call it that way, why won't `document.write(JSONData.value.items[0].author[0].name.$t);` work? Which is what I was trying to use.

Comment: I think I messed something up. I am checking my code. It seems to work in the jsfiddle, so it must be my code.

Comment: Your `document.write` looks legit. One thing you have to watch out for is that JSONData is empty until a callback actually completes. That's why I created the `complete` method and that's why it does that weird, static-like countdown until all 3 requests return. If you try to access JSONData immediately after the foreach finishes, it's almost certainly not populated yet. Feel free to post your other code and I'll check it out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20341/discussion-between-jeramy-and-patrick-m)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just added the functional code to my original post.